# pdf read work in browser but not in mobile device in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have use the [angularjs-pdf](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf) to show the pdf from remote in mobile app using Ionic Framework.

It shows the pdf in browser but it mobile device the blank screen.

Also I have use sample template example from [here](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf/tree/master/example).

If it is not supported please suggest me plugin or another any way to display pdf in mobile app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to show the pdf in the webview using the

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=<your-url>
```

to show the remote pdf, because in android, the webview doesn't directly support to view pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Appears they do not support all browsers with the angualrjs-pdf or rather it's underlying pdf.js dependency doesn't support all mobile browsers https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported

Believe you can "bake in" a browser that might do the trick, but the details I'm not sure about.

---

Would also be good to get some more details if there is any sort of error when you remote debug or any other indication of what the particular failure was.

Comment: I just got the blank screen on my android device

Comment: @SantoshShinde this may help with getting some more information about what failed exactly https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap#chrome-remote-debugging

Comment: please tell me, Is another way to display remote pdf in mobile app itself ?

Comment: Sorry not that I'm aware of... I'm working with a few developers on an ionic app as well but we decided to just do the PDF as a download to avoid the issue of embedded.  You may want to try the ionic forums though they can be very helpful there.